# Понимание strategy pattern

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, шаблон-стратегия

Всем привет.

Получил критику своего кода касательно того, что применяется процедурный стиль написания. Решил уходить от этого. В частности, сейчас разбираю замену if else statement на strategy pattern.
Как один из последних примеров брал http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/08/strategy-design-pattern-tutorial/

По итогу решил сделать вычисление суммы по годовому депозиту - там суть следующая: 
в зависимости от инвестированной клиентом суммы к ней начисляется определенный процент. **Проценты были выбраны следующие:**

- сумма меньше 100 - 1%
- сумма меньше 1000 - 1.5%
- сумма меньше 10000 - 2%
- сумма больше 10000 - 3%

**Применил следующий подход:**

- В интерфейсе `InterestEvaluation` определил метод `getEvaluation`.
- В классах `FirstRate`, `SecondRate`, `ThirdRate`, `FourthRate` реализовываю этот `InterestEvaluation`. В них описал вычисление итоговой суммы для каждого процента.
- В классе `SimpleInterest` создал сделал методы выбора и вызова методов вычисления итоговой суммы.
- В классах `FourthRateEvaluation`, `ThirdRateEvaluation`, `SecondRateEvaluation`, `FirstRateEvaluation` написал вызов нужного метода вычисления исходя из введенной суммы инвестиций.

Как итог, я не смог уйти от if else, хотя, возможно, сделал код немного более масштабируемым.

**Кто встречался с данным паттерном, подскажите, что бы улучшили/поменяли/переделали и вообще можно ли сказать, что мной здесь был применен этот паттерн?**
Спасибо.

**Привожу код ниже и на googleDrive** - https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6zTmwxI7AkyVFl3TGtmOWVTUkE&usp=sharing

**Calculator.java**

```
package com.interestevaluation;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter amount to calculate");
                String giveninvest =  scanner.next();

                StringParsingHelper stringParser = new StringParsingHelper();
                double invest = stringParser.getNumericAmount(giveninvest);

                if (invest <= 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal parameter. Amount " + invest + " <= 0 ");

                if (invest < 100) {
                    FirstRateEvaluation firstRateEvaluation = new FirstRateEvaluation();
                    System.out.println("the first case: " + firstRateEvaluation.tryGetInterestEvaluation(invest));
                    //example of dynamic change evaluation for particular case
                    firstRateEvaluation.setInterestEvaluation(new ThirdRate());
                    System.out.println("the first case modified: " + firstRateEvaluation.tryGetInterestEvaluation(invest));
                } else if(invest < 1000) {
                    SecondRateEvaluation secondRateEvaluation = new SecondRateEvaluation();
                    System.out.println("the second case: " + secondRateEvaluation.tryGetInterestEvaluation(invest));
                } else if(invest < 10000) {
                    ThirdRateEvaluation thirdRateEvaluation = new ThirdRateEvaluation();
                    System.out.println("the third case: " + thirdRateEvaluation.tryGetInterestEvaluation(invest));
                } else {
                    FourthRateEvaluation fourthRateEvaluation = new FourthRateEvaluation();
                    System.out.println("the fourth case: " + fourthRateEvaluation.tryGetInterestEvaluation(invest));
                }

                System.out.println();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
                System.out.println(ie);
                System.out.println("Bad input value. Try again");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**InterestEvaluation.java**

```
package com.interestevaluation;

public interface InterestEvaluation {
    double getEvaluation(double invest);
}

class FirstRate implements InterestEvaluation {
    public double getEvaluation(double invest) {
        return invest*0.01 + invest;
    }
}

class SecondRate implements InterestEvaluation {
    public double getEvaluation(double invest) {
        return invest*0.015 + invest;
    }
}

class ThirdRate implements InterestEvaluation {
    public double getEvaluation(double invest) {
        return invest*0.02 + invest;
    }
}

class FourthRate implements InterestEvaluation {
    public double getEvaluation(double invest) {
        return invest*0.03 + invest;
    }
}
```

**SimpleInterest.java**

```
package com.interestevaluation;

public class SimpleInterest {

    public InterestEvaluation interestEvaluation;

    public void setInterestEvaluation(InterestEvaluation newInterestEvaluation){
        interestEvaluation = newInterestEvaluation;
    }

    public double tryGetInterestEvaluation(double invest){
        return interestEvaluation.getEvaluation(invest);
    }
}
```

**FirstRateEvaluation.java**

```
package com.interestevaluation;

public class FirstRateEvaluation extends SimpleInterest{

    public FirstRateEvaluation(){
        super();
        interestEvaluation = new FirstRate();
    }
}
```

**SecondRateEvaluation.java**

```
package com.interestevaluation;

public class SecondRateEvaluation extends SimpleInterest {

    public SecondRateEvaluation(){
        super();
        interestEvaluation = new SecondRate();
    }
}
```

**ThirdRateEvaluation.java**

```
package com.interestevaluation;

public class ThirdRateEvaluation extends SimpleInterest{

    public ThirdRateEvaluation(){
        super();
        interestEvaluation = new ThirdRate();
    }
}
```

**FourthRateEvaluation.java**

```
package com.interestevaluation;

public class FourthRateEvaluation extends SimpleInterest{

    public FourthRateEvaluation(){
        super();
        interestEvaluation = new FourthRate();
    }
}
```

**StringParsingHelper.java**

```
package com.interestevaluation;

public class StringParsingHelper {

protected double getNumericAmount(final String amount) throws NumberFormatException{
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(amount);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Failed to parse a non-numeric argument: " + amount);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: а в чем смысл разных классов `Evaluation` если им можно присвоить **любой** `Rate`?

Comment: @Grundy В моем понимании для упрощения последующего внесения изменений/доработок в каждом отдельном случае вычисления.

Comment: Стратегия то у вас на самом деле одна, потому что вы все считаете по одной формуле, а изменяете только коэффициент - выносим его в переменные, и получается 0 отличий. А от if-else уйти очень просто - они там потому, что вы захардкодили условие. Вот теперь представьте, как решить такую задачу, если вы заранее не знаете ни сколько будет диапазонов, ни какие у них границы. Представьте, что вы их получаете из какой-то базы данных - в учебных целях замените ее коллекцией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В частности, сейчас разбираю замену if else statement на strategy
>   pattern.
>
> ...
>
> Как итог, я не смог уйти от if else, хотя, возможно, сделал код
>   немного более масштабируемым.

Одно из последствий применения шаблона "стратегия" заключаются не в том, чтобы уйти от if-else, а в том, чтобы уйти от if-else, *разбросанных по коду*. В конечном счете, if-else таки обычно остается -- например в фабрике, которая создает заданную стратегию по каким-то параметрам (в вашем случае это исходная сумма).

Я не видел вашего оригинального кода, но предположу, что код с использованием стратегии должен выглядеть так:

`InterestEvaluate` -- стратегия расчет процентов остается без изменений:

```
package com.interestevaluation;

public interface InterestEvaluation {
    double getEvaluation(double invest);
}

class FirstRate implements InterestEvaluation {
    public double getEvaluation(double invest) {
        return invest*0.01 + invest;
    }
}

class SecondRate implements InterestEvaluation {
    public double getEvaluation(double invest) {
        return invest*0.015 + invest;
    }
}

class ThirdRate implements InterestEvaluation {
    public double getEvaluation(double invest) {
        return invest*0.02 + invest;
    }
}

class FourthRate implements InterestEvaluation {
    public double getEvaluation(double invest) {
        return invest*0.03 + invest;
    }
}
```

`InterestEvaluateFactory` -- фабрика, создающая нужную стратегию:

```
class InterestEvaluateFactory {
    public static InterestEvaluate getEvaluate(double invest) {
        if (invest < 100) {
            return FirstRate();
        } else if(invest < 1000) {
            return SecondRate();
        } else if(invest < 10000) {
            return ThirdRate();
        } else {
            return FourthRate();
        }
    }
}
```

Основная программа:

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter amount to calculate");
                String giveninvest =  scanner.next();

                StringParsingHelper stringParser = new StringParsingHelper();
                double invest = stringParser.getNumericAmount(giveninvest);

                if (invest <= 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal parameter. Amount " + invest + " <= 0 ");

                InterestEvaluate evaluate = InterestEvaluateFactory.getEvaluate(invest);

                System.out.println("Interest: " + evaluate.getEvaluation(invest));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
                System.out.println(ie);
                System.out.println("Bad input value. Try again");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При этом класс `SimpleInterest` и его наследники вам вообще не нужны.

Собственно преимущество в использовании стратегии заключается в двух моментах: вы можете в рантайме менять поведение программы (алгоритм начисления процентов) и вы не дублируете по коду те самые if-else (в вашем примере он один, но в большом приложении таких участков могло бы быть несколько).

Comment: `else` можно было и убрать, `return` же

Comment: @andreycha
Красивое решение. То есть, в данном случае так же дополнительно используется паттерн Factory для создания нужного объекта. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Strategy в принципе, как правило, используется в связке с creational pattern, например, Factory или Builder?

Comment: @Grundy как говорится, "орфография и пунктуация автора сохранена" :).

Comment: @andreycha, справедливости ради, у него не было return :-)

Comment: @JohnKiedis необязательно. Например, у вас есть алгоритм сортировки, который принимает comparer (т.е. стратегию сортировки). Этот алгоритм вы используете из разных мест, в одних местах вам нужна сортировка по возрастанию, в других -- по убыванию. В каждом месте подается свой компаратор в зависимости от нужд. Никакой фабрикой тут не пахнет, конечно же.